# printing out data of array element in java

Tags: java, arrays

If I have an array of a class type (cars) and each car has been given a make and model
using set methods, how can I then print out the make and model of a particular element?
I need to print this out in a separate class

```
public class Car {   

    private String make;
    private String model;

    public void setMake (String str1) {

        make = str1;

    }

    public void setModel (String str2) {

        model = str2;

    }
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to override its toString() method

Comment: Why is _sorting_ tagged here?

Comment: Could we see your Car class then we can advise you on how to add a toString()

Comment: On what basic do you need to pick a car from an array of cars?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `toString()` method to your class

```
public class Car {   

    private String make;
    private String model;

    public void setMake (String str1) {

        make = str1;

    }

    public void setModel (String str2) {

        model = str2;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return "Make  :"+ make + "  Model :" + model;
    }

}
```

### Just printing a car

You can then use this as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   Car car=new Car();
   car.setMake("Audi");
   car.setModel("ModelName");

   System.out.println(car);
}
```

### Printing all of an array

Equally if this exists in an array of cars (I'm using the constructor I introduce in the notes for brevity)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   Car[] cars=new Car[3];
   cars[0]=new Car("Audi","ModelName");
   cars[1]=new Car("BMW","ModelName");
   cars[2]=new Car("Honda","ModelName");

   for(int i=0;i<cars.length;i++){
      System.out.println(cars[i]);
   }
}
```

### Printing after user selects an index

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
        Car[] cars=new Car[3];
        cars[0]=new Car("Audi","ModelName");
        cars[1]=new Car("BMW","ModelName");
        cars[2]=new Car("Honda","ModelName");

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Select index to print, should be between 0 and " + (cars.length-1));

        //checks that user actually inputs an integer, 
        //checking its in range is left as an excercise
        while (scan.hasNextInt()==false){
            scan.next(); //consume bad input
            System.out.println("Select index to print, should be between 0 and " + (cars.length-1));

        }
        int index=scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println(cars[index]);


    }
```

#### Notes

It seems like the make and model are essential to the workings of the car class, consider changing your constructor to take them as arguments

```
public Car(String make, String model){
    this.make=make;
    this.model=model;
}
```

All this assumes you already have the element you wish to print

Comment: Just adding `toString()` is not the solution. I guess(from the title and the question description) that the OP wants to find a particular car from an array of cars, and print that one alone. Why override the `toString()` for that? Just calling the 2 getters in the SOP is enough. Also, since the OP hasn't mentioned on what basic the car needs to be selected from the array of cars, we need to ask the OP about it.

Comment: @R.J "how can I then print out the make and model of a particular element"

Comment: *If I have an array of a class type (cars) and each car has been given a make and model using set methods, how can I then print out the make and model of a particular element?* - I really doubt if the problem is with printing. I think OP wants to be able to figure out on how to get that particular element(may be based on make or model) and print that. *PRINT* shouldn't or rather isn't the priority here.

Comment: @R.J If the OP changes their question to ask something different I'll be happy to change my answer. But this is the answer to the question asked. I'm not going to assume this can't possibly be their question

Comment: I don't have the element I wish to print. My program asks the user to pick an element from the array and print the details of that element, how can I do this?

Comment: @user2877543 Then you need to include in your question what basis the element is picked upon. For example the user inputing an index?

Comment: @RichardTingle-You added the arrays part after I commented. Your answer seems to answer the vague question(after the edit with the array part), therefore, its fine.

Comment: But now, I would expect another edit in your answer(based on the OP's comment). ;)

Comment: @R.J Fair enough, I think you are right though, the OP does want something *more*, we'll have to wait and see exactly what "more" is (although I'm not a big fan of [chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions))

Comment: @RichardTingle - Same goes with me. And that's the reason, I didn't bother posting an answer, which I would have to edit, as and when the OP keeps spilling the beans.

Comment: @R.J Seems you were half right, rather than editing to spill the beans the OP has just [re asked the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447672/printing-data-of-specific-element-from-array-in-java) without any beans

Comment: @R.J Is the "Printing after user selects an index" section what you ment?

Comment: @RichardTingle - Yep, thats the thing!:) Now this looks a complete answer to what you can call, a bits and pieces question. Here have a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car{

    String make ;
    String model;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return "make  :"+ this.make + "  model :" + this.model;
    }
}

List<Car> list= new ArrayList<Car>();

Car c1=new Car();
Car c2=new Car();
Car c3=new Car();
Car c4=new Car();
list.add(c1);
list.add(c2);
list.add(c3);
list.add(c4);

for(Car car : list)
{
    System.out.println(car);    
}
```

Comment: @MarsOne It looks pretty java-e to me

Comment: sorry forgot to add I need to print this out in another class

Comment: Just adding `toString()` is not the solution. I guess(from the title and the question description) that the OP wants to find a particular car from an array of cars, and print that one alone. Why override the `toString()` for that? Just calling the 2 getters in the SOP is enough. Also, since the OP hasn't mentioned on what basic the car needs to be selected from the array of cars, we need to ask the OP about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private static String toString(sample[] carTypes)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < carTypes.length; i++)
        {
            if (carTypes[i] != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(" Name : ");
                stringBuilder.append(carTypes[i].name);
                stringBuilder.append(",");
                stringBuilder.append(" Model : ");
                stringBuilder.append(carTypes[i].model);
                stringBuilder.append(",");
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString().substring(0, stringBuilder.toString().length() - 1);
    }
```

output :

```
Name : BMW, Model : Mark 3, Name : AUDI, Model : A-6, Name : BENZ, Model : BZ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Car {   

    private String make;
    private String model;

    public Car(String make, String model) {
       this.make = make;
       this.model = model;
    }

    public void setMake (String str1) {

        make = str1;

    }

    public void setModel (String str2) {

        model = str2;

    }

    public String getMake() {
      return make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
      return model;
    }
}

public class PrintCars {
   public static void main(String []args) {

          Car cars[] = new Car[10];
          // Assume you populate the array with Car objects here by code
          cars[0] = new Car("make1", "model1");
          for (Car carObj : cars) {
            System.out.println(carObj.getmake());
            System.out.println(carObj.getmodel());
          }
    }
}
```