# printing data of specific element from array in java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have an array of a class type which stores videos (not real ones just objects).
Each video has a title and an author.
The videos have their data set using set methods like these:

```
 public class Clip {

 private String title;
 private String author;

     public void setTitle (String s1) {

        title = s1;

    }

     public void setAuthor (String s2) {

        title = s2;

    }
```

I then have a different class which creates the array and uses these set methods to enter data.
The program then asks the user to select an element from the array, for example the user
selects element [3]. Now the program must print the title and author of that element(video).

This is the part I am not sure how to do?
Can I please have some help?

Comment: You are creating new strings in setters. Please don't do that. That should be `this.title = s1;`

Comment: what's the issue? Search for override `toString()`.

Comment: can you please show an example?

Comment: This is exactly the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446929/printing-out-data-of-array-element-in-java just with a different example

Comment: @RichardTingle is right. This is not done. You should have give more details in that question by editing it. Richard had an almost proper answer for it. Closing this as duplicate.

Comment: @Suresh atta - How is he creating new strings? What dou you mean by that. He's passing a string reference and then assign it to the private field. There is no String constructor included, so basically it's all about references.

Comment: Is by any chance what you want the "Printing after user selects an index" of my [now edited answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19447072/2187042) to the duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of Clip class is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
public class Clip {
        private String title;
        private String author;

        public Clip(String title, String author) {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getAuthor() {
            return author;
        }

        public void setAuthor(String author) {
            this.author = author;
        }
    }
```

And you can retrieve your objects from array like this:

```
@Test
    public void testClipArray() throws Exception {
        // Lets assume our array contains 2 elements
        Clip[] clipArray = new Clip[2];
        clipArray[0] = new Clip("First", "Clip");
        clipArray[1] = new Clip("Second", "Clip");

        // Lets retrieve 2nd object (with index: 1)
        Clip secondObject = clipArray[1];

        System.out.println(secondObject.getAuthor());
        System.out.println(secondObject.getTitle());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Override toString() then simply call

```
System.out.println(element[3])
```

If you need help creating the toString method eclipse can show you how it's done.

Press Alt+Shift+S then S , or right click -> Source -> generate toString()

Comment: Yeah, thats what [I thought](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19447072/2187042) too, seemingly that doesn't answer the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two options:

1. Create getters in the Video-Class, e.g.`public String getTitle() { return title; }`
2. Override the `toString` function to output the value you want, e.g.

   @Override 
   public String toString() { 
     return "Author: " + author + ", Title: " + title"; 
   }

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Clip {

private String title;
private String author;

 public void setTitle (String s1) {

    title = s1;

}

 public void setAuthor (String s2) {

    author = s2;

}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return author + ": " + title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override toString method of Clip. Every invocation of print* (e.g. println) method would call toString method of an object.

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[Title: " + this.title +", Author: " + this.author + "]";
    }
```

Example after overriding method:

```
    Clip clip1 = new Clip();
    Clip clip2 = new Clip();
    Clip[] clipArray = {clip1, clip2};

    for (Clip clip : clipArray) {
        System.out.println(clip);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please override toString () of  Clip class as below

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return "Title:"+ this.s1 + "  Author:" + this.s2;
}


Then print the Title and Author by using the below code.
System.out.println(objectClip.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Override toString() method in Clip class as follows,

```
 @override
   public String toString(){ 

    return "Title: "+ title +"  ,author"+author;

   }
```

and invocation code invoke following statement,

```
System.out.println(element[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Override toString() method of Clip class. For example,

```
public class Clip {

    private String title;
    private String author;

    public void setTitle (String s1) {
        title = s1;
    }

    public void setAuthor (String s2) {
        title = s2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + " by " + author;
    }
}
```

Then print the array of clips as follows:

```
for (Clip aClip : arrayOfClips) {
    System.out.println(aClip);
}
```